# Altium: Set width of net class

Tags: pcb, altium

Is it possible to select a whole **net class** and change its track width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a rule in the schematic, if you select the "Parameter Set" go to "Add..." and select "Rule" you can add a "Width Constraint" and that will set a rule for all nets in that net class

if you want to actually change the track width itself in the pcb you can use the "PCB Filter" to select all the nets you want with the filter:

(InNet('NetA') or InNet('NetA')) and IsTrack

and then using Ctrl + A to select them all and edit the "Width" in "Properties". Please note that in Altium NEXUS (3.0.13) there is a bug that you have to manually clear this mask in "PCB Filter" or you can't select other things again even if you clear the mask with Ctrl + left click

I'm sure there is a more direct way to select nets and net classes, but this is what i found to be fastest

Comment: I almost managed to do that. I got all the way to `...and edit the "Width" in "Properties" ` but then when I right click and select properties and change the track width, it only allows me to change the track I right-clicked on and not all the selected tracks. Or if I don't right click a track, it won't show me the properties dialog.

Comment: can you get properties to pop up as a sidebar? Maybe try hitting tab to bring up properties. what version of altium are you using?

Comment: Oh thank you, I think I figured it out. I had to open the PCB Inspector and then I was able to change it in there. Somehow it doesn't bring this up when I right click and choose properties. So, for posterity -> Bottom right corner choose `PCB` -> `PCB Inspector`. I am using Altium 15 btw. so I suppose things might be a little bit different with newer versions.